# In Genesis 6:7, what is the reason given for God’s destruction of animals (other than humans)?

Tags: genesis

In Genesis 6:7, it is written,

> <sup>7</sup> So the LORD said, “I will destroy man whom I have created from the face of the earth, both man and beast, creeping thing and birds of the air, for I am sorry that I have made them.” <sup>NKJV, ©1982</sup>

The reason for God’s destruction of humankind is explicitly stated in the previous two verses:

> <sup>5</sup> Then the LORD saw that the wickedness of man was great in the earth, and that every intent of the thoughts of his heart was only evil continually. <sup>6</sup> And the LORD was sorry that He had made man on the earth, and He was grieved in His heart. <sup>NKJV, ©1982</sup>

However, what reason does the Bible give for God destroying the rest of animal creation, such as the creeping things, birds of the air, etc.?

<sup>This [related question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38455/gods-decision-regarding-the-great-flood) seems focused on the reconciliation of an apparent contradiction but does not necessarily ask for the basis of the extermination of the animals in the flood.</sup>

Comment: The reason is not given here but later in chapter 6:12, "And God saw the earth, and behold, it was corrupt, for all flesh had corrupted their way on the earth." (ESV). The implication here is that all flesh including birds, animals, humans were corrupted. How exactly they have been corrupted I cannot say, but it seems clear enough in the bible that all mammals were corrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I’ve been told off for giving “answers” in the comment section I’m forced to answer here. So I’ll give a longer comment rather a short blurb.

Please read this response on a different question I answered. Once you understand the context I’m operating in then you will follow my short answer below

[What is meant by "The iniquity of the Amorites is not yet full" in Genesis 15:16?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20971/what-is-meant-by-the-iniquity-of-the-amorites-is-not-yet-full-in-genesis-1516/38272#38272)

The answer lies in this verse

“G-d looked on the earth, and behold, it was corrupt; for *all flesh had corrupted their way upon the earth*.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:12‬ ‭NASB‬‬

The implication being that the elohim (sons of G-d) not only corrupted the DNA or seed of humans but they also corrupted the seeds or DNA of animals too. And so G-d maintained a set of clean undefiled animals for the ark and they got loaded in. You will find references in the Bible in my linked answer to hybrids between humans and animals.

That’s why the animals and birds were destroyed not just the humans and yes I believe it was a world wide flood in a Biblical Cosmology of an enclosed Terrarium surrounded by waters. There is a possibility that animals in the waters on the earth were also corrupted too but that’s a different discussion.

I’m not being dogmatic, I’m offering an alternative view. If you demand references besides the Bible I won’t be providing any but I do not take credit for this concept or explanation.

Comment: I am curious how the DNA of creeping things was corrupted...?

Comment: Were they? The idea of flesh in my mind implies nephesh and it is my understanding that only animals higher up in the animal kingdom have a nephesh. So the insect world may have been preserved in eggs waiting like seeds for the right conditions to “germinate”. That’s pure speculation. I’ve considered the same question myself. Not awfully troubled by it for now.

Comment: Well, they were destroyed (“both man and beast, creeping thing and birds of the air”), so presumably their DNA was corrupted—if we assume according to your answer that God destroyed creation because its DNA was corrupted.

Comment: I guess you are right. Egypt has a beetle god. So in the same way that human and animal hybrids were created, not through sexual contact as with human females presumably, but through “dark magic or occultic practices”. The creeping things were corrupted through witchcraft which the sons of god are presumed to have known given the magicians of pharaoh imitating Moses’ plagues up until a point. They followed gnosticism or hidden knowledge. So my answer is through gnostic witchcraft of the gods. Similar way that Nimrod became a nephilim through some witchcraft because he wasn’t born a beast.

Comment: DNA being equal size on all living animals and identical in format, components and function but not in sequence. And notice I said beast, that then ties into the mark of the beast being genetic and of the kind that alters the human genome to the point that it would be irredeemable because Jesus did not die for elohim or ‘angels’ but only for humans or part humans (preach to every **creature** the gospel of the kingdom). Nimrod is believed to have completely altered his DNA or at least the part that still made him human.